# Rust off-chain solutions

Tags: transaction, offchain, learning

I am interested in learning Rust and I thought a good idea of doing so would be to build something on Cardano. What libraries and resources would you recommend for someone like me? I am specially interested in building, balancing and evaluating transactions (including possibly smart contracts).

Answer (score 2):

[Naumachia](https://github.com/MitchTurner/naumachia) is specifically designed to make off-chain code easy with Rust. It uses [CML](https://github.com/dcSpark/cardano-multiplatform-lib) under the hood for actually deploying/transacting, but that's much too low-level for the average developer IMO, and Naumachia abstracts away a lot of the headache with declarative APIs. There are just a number of features that are still WIP.

Naumachia also comes with testing infrastructure for creating ScriptContexts for testing your On-Chain code, as well as mock chains for testing your contract as a whole. It also syncs with the `trireme` cli for managing your test environments/keys.

There are multiple "Sample dApps" which are functional examples of Naumachia [here](https://github.com/MitchTurner/naumachia/tree/master/sample-dApps). A lot of progress has been made since the README was written, but everything on there is still relevant to get your started. I'm hoping to add more tutorials soon, and hopefully a Demeter template as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Cardano Multiplatform Lib](https://github.com/dcSpark/cardano-multiplatform-lib).

It can be deployed to multiple platforms (Rust crate would be what you are interested in) and it handles:

- Serialization & deserialization of Cardano core data structures
- Useful utility functions for DApps and wallets